# How could I use Mathematica to remove finger tips that appear in images?

Tags: image-processing

I used my photo camera to "scan" a heavy dictionary. I tried to have flat images by pressing the margins of the pages with my fingers.

The color of the background is (normally) black  and my fingers have different colors from the color of the page margins.

My questions is: Is  it possible to  apply Mathematica photo tools to automatically remove the finger tips from the scanned pages?

For experiments, you can  freely use the following photo

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY9cp.jpg"]
```

[image: photo]

Comment: It's a good idea to show what what you have done so far, and where you have got stuck, otherwise it looks like you're simply asking other people to write your code for you.

Comment: If the finger tips are in the margins why not simply crop them out?

Comment: Next time wear bright red gloves for easy post-processing...:)

Comment: @s0rce It is very easily to crop the bottom side but then I have to find some way to re-fill the cropped margin in a "natural" way! This seems difficult to me!

Comment: @kornaros Why do you need to refill the margins? You can easily find out the bounding box of the textual matter on each page and crop everything else. Then, use a Hough transform (use `ImageLines`) to find the orientation of the text and correct it to make all the pages horizontal. Then you can whiten the background and re-pad the margins to your desired thickness.

Comment: I found the title of this question, less the last three words that wrapped to the next line, quite disturbing.  We don't support automated torture at [Mathematica.SE]. :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard _Mathematica_ has built-in support for that — use `Chop`. If you're worried the neighbours might hear the screams, there's always `Quiet` ;)

Comment: @rm-rf How one could easily find the bounded box of the textual matter?  Another problem that I faced a lot of times: The bounding  box of a scanned page is not always a perfect rectangle(with right angles) but a four edge polygon that must be transformed to a right(ie. orthogonal) rectangle. Do you have some idea how to capture the textual data for the general case?

Answer (score 22):

Here's a way to approach fingertip removal using some of the morphological operations:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY9cp.jpg"];
blurImg = ImageAdjust[ImageConvolve[img, ConstantArray[0.01, {100, 100}]]];
bw = Erosion[MorphologicalBinarize[blurImg, 0.67], 50];
boundBox = MorphologicalComponents[bw, Method -> "BoundingBox"];
mask = Erosion[Image[boundBox], 130];
ImageAdjust[ImageMultiply[img, mask]]
```

[image]

The first step in the processing blurs the image (a 100x100 filter kernel is used). This is then binarized and eroded to give a black and white image that roughly includes the text area. The `MorphologicalComponents` command makes this a rectangular bounding box, which is then eroded to remove the fingertips. The final step multiplies the eroded bounding box with the original image.

Comment: Very nice! is there a way without using "magic" numbers (like 0.67)?

Comment: @belisarius -- the procedure isn't terribly sensitive to the threshold value, but of course this may vary depending on the image.

Answer (score 13):

This may help:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9s3p.png"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
m = Dilation[Binarize[ColorSeparate[i, "HSB"][[2]]], 3]
i1 = Inpaint[i, m, Method -> {"TextureSynthesis"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Interesting this `Inpaint`function.

Comment: @Murta The `TotalVariation`and `NavierStokes` methods are very beautiful